# Как реализовать модели?

Tags: django, django-model

У меня есть 2-а приложения(Р) c моделями(М):

1. products **Р**

   1.1. Product **М** - модель с товарами и базовой информацией о нём эта информация будет у всех товаров одинаковая как цена или количество
2. catalog **Р**

   2.1. Category **М** - модель с категориями к примеру процессоры и видеокарты

   2.1.1. Characteristic **М** - подмодель Category с уникальными характеристиками для этой категории к 
     примеру у категории процессоры это сокет а у видеокарты тип памяти

   2.1.1.1. Content **М** - значение этой характеристики к примеру сокет может быть АМ4 ИЛИ АМ1

Теперь о связях:

Product (Т - товары) связаны один ко многим с категориями у одной категории может быть много товаров

```
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
```

Category (К - категория) является самой верхней моделью

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название категории', max_length=30)
```

Characteristic (НХ - название характеристики) - связана один ко многим с каталогом у одного каталога может быть много характеристик

```
class Characteristic(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
    name = models.CharField('Название характеристики', max_length=50)
```

Content (З - значение) - связь один ко многим с характеристикой у одной характеристики может быть много значений

```
class Content(models.Model):
    characteristic = models.ForeignKey(Characteristic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='характеристика')
    content = models.CharField(verbose_name=characteristic.name, unique=True, max_length=150)
```

Как это выглядит в графическом плане чтобы лучше понять:

[image: схема]

Как должно работать:

Когда мы выбираем **товару** **категорию** к которой он будет привязан **категория** будет передавать модели с **товарами** **характеристики** со **значениями** специфичны для данной **категории**

Вопрос такой как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты можешь получить доступ к характеристикам что привязаны к категории через атрибут `characteristic_set` у объекта категории. То есть твой полный код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```py
Product.objects.get(pk = 'тут ты должен указать primary key для продукта').categories.characteristic_set.all()
```

Более подробно ты можешь прочитать [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: Да я могу использовать это во вюхе и потом в шаблонах но проблема в другом 
Когда я создаю категорию( CategoryAdmin ) в админке я могу сразу заполнить характеристики и ещё есть отдельное представление характеристики (CharacteristicAdmin) где я могу заполнить значения а в товарах не могу потмоу что не знаю как
С помощью модуля django-nested-inline я могу вложить инлайны друг в друга мне надо чтобы когда я выбрал продукту и даль ему категорию выводились характеристики этой категории и я мог выбрать им значения потом это всё сохранялась данному продукту надеюсь смог изложить понятно)))

Comment: То-есть модель характеристики и значения это как шаблон со значениями которые мы можем пополнять чтобы потом их использовали товары чтобы потом написать на их основе уникальные фильтры для категории чтобы сортировать по уникальным характеристикам возможно идея бредовая но на ум других реализаций не пришло

Comment: Я не работал с `django-nested-inline`, но, я думаю, что если ты хочешь реализовать то что задумал, то как минимум тебе стоит прикрутить лишний `ForeignKey` к значению характеристики, который будет вести к товару. Таким образом ты сможешь сделать инлайн от товара к значению характеристики, где через встроенный в джанго виджет для `ForeignKey` будешь выбирать характеристику к которой относится значение. Метод очень костыльный, но связь между товарами и значениями характеристик быть должна. Поэкспериментируй с этим и может придешь к результату, который тебя устроит...

Comment: Если бы я лично пытался бы сделать нечто подобное, то, скорее всего, я бы попробовал потанцевать с бубном и аяксом вокруг смены значения категории для продукта и менял бы каждый раз пул для значений характеристик. Очевидно, что это далеко не оптимальный способ. Скорее всего в `django-nested-inline` уже существует готовое решение так что настоятельно рекомендую изучить документацию. А ещё мне кажется что связь между характеристикой и значением должна быть `OneToOne`, но это субъективно...